# Show that the limit of the sequence ${(n+a)(n+b)}^{\frac{1}{2}}-n =\frac{a+b}{2}, n\to\infty $, where $a>0, b>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I tried to find the limit of
\begin{equation}
((n+a)(n+b))^{\frac{1}{2}}-n =\frac{a+b}{2},  a>0, b>0
\end{equation}
I took the help of rationalization
\begin{align}
((n+a)(n+b))^{\frac{1}{2}}-n &=((n+a)(n+b))^{\frac{1}{2}}-n \times \frac{((n+a)(n+b))^{\frac{1}{2}}+n}{((n+a)(n+b))^{\frac{1}{2}}+n}\\
&=\frac{(n+a)(n+b)-n^{2}}{{((n+a)(n+b))}^{\frac{1}{2}}+n}\\
&=\frac{n^{2}[(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})-1]}{n[({(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n}))}^{\frac{1}{2}}+1]}\\
&=\frac{n^{2}[(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})-1]}{n[{((1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n}))}^{\frac{1}{2}}+1]}\\
&=\frac{n[(1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n})-1]}{{((1+\frac{a}{n})(1+\frac{b}{n}))}^{\frac{1}{2}}+1}\\
\end{align}

After that, I am unable to solve the problem further. Would like to get few valuable tips from you.

Comment: The same rationalization extends a little further, see [Values of the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left(\sqrt{(x+a)(x+b)}-x\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708429/values-of-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-left-sqrtxaxb-x-right)

Comment: The limit as n tends to what?

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon Thanks

Comment: @Ihraaq  I edited the question. BTW the question is the same as suggested by Teresa

Comment: @TheIotaa Welcome!